# Svelte/Vite/Typescript source map in browser all of a sudden broken

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools, svelte, vite, source-maps

I have a Svelte project where I'm used to debug my .svelte files inside the web browser in dev tools.

Don't know what changed but now searching for svelte files returns the processed javascript files.  The mapped files are there, but I'm really wondering what happened.  I just want to hide those javascript generated files.

Heres a screenshot showing the "duplicate" files:

[image: Duplicate files Map & Javascript]

I even tried to recreate a simple vanilla Vite/Svelte/Typescript project and face the same behavior.

Thought it was a chrome issue, but when I start my project with "npm run preview" only the typescript file shows.

Really wondering where is the problem

Comment: Same issue with React + TypeScript. I see ts/tsx files in the browser, but the content is compiled JS

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems to be related to Chromium.  I have the problem with Chrome 111.

I tested on a computer with Chrome 105 and its working well.  So something broke in a recent Chrome update.

I'll open another Question for that

Comment: Any news about the problem?

Comment: For what it's worth - I also encountered the same problem (both in Chromium and Edge, working fine in Firefox) :(

Answer (score 0):

@Nickon

Problem been reported to Chromium :

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1425475

Didn't had time to create a sample though